# Extend background image to navigation bar Experthive

Tags: wordpress, header

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCifu.png)
The background image doesn't cover the navigation bar using experthive. We tried this code but it was not possible to click on the navigation bar anymore. We changed the z-indexes but still didn't work. Do you have any suggestions to modify the code or to solve our issue? Many thanks

```
.site-header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home .header-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 48px; /* Adjust the height of the navigation bar as needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: auto; /* Add this line to enable pointer events on the navigation bar */
}

.home .header-navbar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://protravaux.ma/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/nolan-issac-K5sjajgbTFw-unsplash.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Add any additional styles to the navigation bar elements as desired */
.header-navbar__start,
.header-navbar__middle,
.header-navbar__end {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

We tried the code above